# Alexa - Python, There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 404 : NOT FOUND

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, alexa-skills-kit, ngrok, alexa-slot

I am using flask with python to develop my code for an Alexa skill which fetched Wikipedia data. I am also using Wikipedia library of Python.

Every time I try to test my skill Service simulator gives an error. Please help me find the error.

"There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 404 : NOT FOUND"

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session
import json
import requests
import time
import unidecode
import wikipedia


app = Flask(__name__)
ask = Ask(app,"/wiki_reader")

def get_wikisummary(searchitem):
    summ=wikipedia.summary(searchitem,sentences=3)
    sober=[unidecode.unidecode(summ)]
    return sober

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "hi there, how ya doin?"

@ask.launch
    def start_skill():
    welcome_message='Hi, ask me about any country of the World'
    return question(welcome_message)

@ask.intent("AnswerIntent")
def answer(ans):
    summ1=get_wikisummary(ans)
    summ2=[unidecode.unidecode(summ1)]
    return statement("{}",format(summ2))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am using ngrok to host code which is currently hosted on localhost, on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out I was trying to run multiple codes on a single port. This is why it was giving not found error.